# Telerik Kendo UI Of area Chart How display dark color of area

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Hi I am drawing kendo UI chart with dark color but when i draw the chart with this  seriesColors: ["#ffbf00"], it will show lighter color but i want full dark color i have attached image you can see area chart draw is very light color.I need same color show before the text of Phase 2 it is pure yellow or dark but in area chart show lighter i need dark color to represent the chart  [image: I need same color show before the text of Phase 2 it is pure yellow or dark but in area chart show lighter i need dark color to represent the chart]

Comment: You would likely get more answers if you post some codes that you have used to represent the chart, as well as any styling and markup that you have used. Providing just an image of what you want to accomplish without any accompanying evidence you have tried something is really not the best way to get help here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have this dark effect because your graph is transparent, to change the color of the legend, set the opacity (so as to have the color you set), then choose a color darker for the Series so as to have the same color both

to change the opacity:

```
  seriesDefaults: {
       type: "area",
       stack: true,
       opacity: 1
    },
```

getting something like [that](https://dojo.telerik.com/AyEzoSiR)